# Find out which threads consume CPU in JBoss?

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I have some threads consuming lots of CPU and want to find them.

I am on a linux machine. SUSE. While use top and turn threads ON, it shows threads consuming high cpu:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+   PPID COMMAND                                        
28597 acrosspm  20   0 3682m 2.8g  23m R   99  4.4 128:51.01 28481 java                                           
28593 acrosspm  20   0 3682m 2.8g  23m R   97  4.4 129:03.77 28481 java                                           
28598 acrosspm  20   0 3682m 2.8g  23m R   97  4.4 129:12.65 28481 java                                           
28600 acrosspm  20   0 3682m 2.8g  23m R   97  4.4 128:59.34 28481 java                                           
28610 acrosspm  20   0 3682m 2.8g  23m R   97  4.4 129:18.72 28481 java
```

but when I use jstack -F 28481, it doesn't match the busiest threads id.

I tried to use jconsole and jvisualvm. None of them are able to sample thread data, because I think the jmx has broken (I can connect to via jmx before CPU of the process jumped to 2000%)

So is there any other way I can find out the call stack of the cpu consuming thread?

Many thanks.

---

Some part of thread dump will be:

```
Thread 28641 "MSC service thread 1-2": (state = BLOCKED)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Thread 28640 "MSC service thread 1-1": (state = BLOCKED)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Thread 28638 "Reference Reaper": (state = BLOCKED)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007825b8268> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007825b8268> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.jboss.modules.ref.References$ReaperThread.run(References.java:68)

VM Thread 28636 "Service Thread": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28635 "C1 CompilerThread14": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28634 "C1 CompilerThread13": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28633 "C1 CompilerThread12": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28632 "C1 CompilerThread11": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28631 "C1 CompilerThread10": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28630 "C2 CompilerThread9": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28629 "C2 CompilerThread8": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28628 "C2 CompilerThread7": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28627 "C2 CompilerThread6": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28626 "C2 CompilerThread5": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28625 "C2 CompilerThread4": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28624 "C2 CompilerThread3": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28623 "C2 CompilerThread2": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28622 "C2 CompilerThread1": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28621 "C2 CompilerThread0": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28620 "JDWP Event Helper Thread": (state = BLOCKED)

VM Thread 28619 "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket": (state = BLOCKED)

Thread 28618 "Signal Dispatcher": (state = BLOCKED)

Thread 28617 "Finalizer": (state = BLOCKED)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000782459cf0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

Thread 28616 "Reference Handler": (state = BLOCKED)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:125)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000781816e20> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that all those threads are Garbage Collection threads.

Our program generates very very large object and kept in memory.

When the heap running low, gc threads will do their works. And since all those objects are in old region, and none of them can be released, the threads keep running FGC.

That's why the cpu so high.